# How to declare yield type of generator with TypeScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, generator

I have this generator function which yields random values from an array:

```
export const fisherYatesShuffle = function* <T>(deck: Array<T>) : Generator<T, void, T> {
    for (let i = deck.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        const swapIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        [deck[i], deck[swapIndex]] = [deck[swapIndex], deck[i]];
        yield deck[i];
    }
};
```

when I iterate over it:

```
for(const V of fisherYatesShuffle<string>(['a','b','c'])){
  // typeof V here should be string
}
```

but TS doesn't seem to know that V is a string.

anyone know if there is a fix?

Comment: [I'm using your code exactly, and the type is inferred correctly](https://i.ibb.co/6ZJghtS/type.png).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your return type is wrong.

You can use

- `Generator<T, void, unknown>` which is what the compiler infers
- `Generator<T, void, T | undefined` since `next()` can also return `undefined`

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7wGYEtUAthQCaAhjMKgMq4CuGGANsHALxwbXIIxYoBUcAHgAqAPgAUAE2AIA1gC44AQShRiAT2EiAlHAUBxYMgKlowgDRwAbhCwSLHGcggB3ZCLgBvAFBxfbaHBijPBYLHBSsgB0jMgA5jC4cAC0cACMANxwoSKsAAyZWElJOt5+ZYgo6HCozsRgAJLIUiBhALKkuJEMENBi7QmRqk0QALZiOvxioQDUaVpa6T7lvgDaETIrWAC6FusrNXWNzVtbYWvSGwcNTaA74RebJ4vLvmpYwPQS97KPz34Avl5-osvBhekg0PAAGpwCAYNg4fBEUjkKi0BjAAToKBYOLiFYAcmIBLMBIARiSCQgCVt5qU4AB6BlwGBqMDAOFwGFIph4CDUT5wMm8mA4uJArxeIA)

Comment: Or just don't annotate it at all